# C# windows phone 8 app paragraph

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

Hello I am new to Windows Phone app development. I am right now developing an app that shows a paragraph of text. I used a scroll viewer in order to show the text. I have put the entire paragraph in to a single text block. the problem is when I run the app the emulator displays only half of the text and the remaining half is not visible how to make all the text inside the paragraph visible??. Thank you

Comment: Maybe the scroll viewer control isn't the right one for such things. The scroll viewer control is for scrolling invisible content...Try a simple Grid or Stackpanel

Comment: could u post your code

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
TextWrapping="Wrap" on TextBlock
```

Also make sure scrollviewer size is not set to Auto as it will keep expanding to accommodate the text. Try to give screen width size.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock Text="Your paragraph here" TextWrapping="Wrap" /> 
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use RichTextBox for it like:

`<RichTextBox FontSize="25" Background="Transparent">
    <Paragraph>
         your text goes here.
     </Paragraph>
 </RichTextBox>`

Comment: i used the RichTextBox but still it displayed only a few texts and the remaining was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code.

XAML Code :

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
   <StackPanel>                
       <RichTextBox x:Name="richTxtBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Style="{StaticResource NormalRichTextBoxStyle}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Class Code :-

```
string str = "*****  Your String  *****";   
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

Run myRun = new Run();
myRun.Text = str;
p.Inlines.Add(myRun); 

richTxtBox.Blocks.Add(p);
```